# What does "a tenu à remercier M. Macron" precisely mean?

Tags: sens, expressions

I have another question actually on the very same paragraph from [this article](http://www.lemonde.fr/proche-orient/article/2017/11/18/liban-l-ex-premier-ministre-saad-hariri-recu-a-l-elysee-par-emmanuel-macron_5216992_3218.html) on Le Monde. It uses the phrase "a tenu à remercier M. Macron".

> Dans la cour de l’Elysée, à l’issue de son entretien avec le chef de l’Etat puis d’un déjeuner « familial », M. Hariri, qui était accompagné de sa femme et de son fils aîné, a tenu à remercier M. Macron qui, dans cette crise, « a fait preuve d’une amitié infaillible ».
>
> In the courtyard of the Elysée, at the end of his interview with the head of state and a "family lunch", Saad Hariri, who was accompanied by his wife and eldest son, was happy to thank Emmanuel Macron who, in this crisis, "demonstrated an infallible friendship".

I looked up this use of tenir, and found [this entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenir#French) on Wiktionary.

> **tenir:** 8. (followed by the preposition à) to be attached to something, to be fond of something, to hold something dear

Am I right to understand the phrase "a tenu à remercier M. Macron" as an example of this? In which case, how should I translate the phrase?

Is my current translation, "was happy to thank Emmanuel Macron", ideal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite. The expression "tenir à + infinitif" is commonly used in both conversation and writing — with the meaning of "***vouloir (fortement)*** faire quelque chose".

You can say, for instance:

> Dites-moi pourquoi vous **tenez** tant **à** en savoir plus sur cette affaire ?
>
> En préambule, je **tiens à** vous avertir que ...
>
> Ce n'est pas que je ne vous fais pas confiance. Je **tenais** juste **à** m'en assurer.

The phrase in your example is a *passé-composé* variant of this expression:

> « X a tenu à remercier Y » === « X a (fortement) voulu remercier Y »
>
> {in English}: "X insisted on thanking Y" or "X was keen to show his appreciation to Y"

Note: The expression also takes the form of "tenir à ce que + subjonctif" when the subject in the subordinate clause  differs from that of "tenir à":

> Je **tiens à ce que** ce soit vous qui vous en occupiez. — {***je*** tiens à / ***ce*** soit}

Comment: Ah, I see. Would this be good? "... **profoundly thanked** Emmanuel Macron"? Or would the simple "... **thanked** Emmanuel Macron" be better, even though it loses some of the nuance?

Comment: @ktm5124 No! The idea of "fortement / strongly" is attached to "***want*** to do", not to the verb "remercier". So it is like: "X (strongly / really) ***wanted to*** express his appreciation to Y". NOT: "X wanted to express his (***great***) appreciation to Y". If you want to say "thank Y profoundly", then "X tient à remercier ***vivement*** Y".

Comment: That makes sense. Then "... (really) wanted to thank Emmanuel Macron" should work, right? Both with and without an adverb such as "really" or "strongly".

Comment: @ktm5124 Not quite. The idea of "fortement / strongly" is an ***integral*** part of this expression. In a manner of speaking, you could get away with thinking that "tenir à faire" is a strong version of "vouloir faire".

Comment: Interesting. So, "really wanted to thank Emmanuel Macron" and "strongly wanted to thank Emmanuel Macron" both hit the bull's eye. I think I'll use one of those then.